# Loose XAML Not Responsive in IE

Tags: xaml, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

Loose XAML is not responsive in Internet Explorer on some computers.

For the code below:

- The controls to not respond visually (or with focus) to mouse clicks.
- I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to set focus on either control.
- Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> on the `ComboBox` does not display the dropdown.
- Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> on the `Button` does appear visually to perform a click.

File `simple.xaml`:

```
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Label>Enabled:</Label>
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Yes</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>No</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button>OK</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This only happens on some computers.  On others, the controls are fully responsive.

I have tried: Internet Explorer (no addons), full reset of IE Settings, confirmed Loose XAML enabled in IE Settings, Developer Tools (nothing useful), searching Google.

Why is Loose XAML not responsive on Internet Explorer for some computers?  How can I further debug this issue?

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"... XAML is hosted in Silverlight in IE (Silverlight is an activeX control). Also Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons... locate Silverlight in the list and double click it to display its properties page....ensure you have the latest version installed.. there were critical updates at the beginning of this year.